# Change the value of a column, based on another column (for certain rows)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
category <- c("Shirts", "Shirts", "Shirts", "Sweaters", "Sweaters")
subcategory <- c("V-Neck","V-Neck","Round","Striped","Striped")
df <- data.frame(ID,category,subcategory)

ID  category   subcategory
1   Shirts     V-Neck
2   Shirts     V-Neck
3   Shirts     Round
4   Sweaters   Striped
5   Sweaters   Striped
```

I want to assign the name of the column "subcategory" to the column "category" for all rows, where category == "Shirts"

My result should look like this:

```
ID  category   subcategory
1   V-Neck     V-Neck
2   V-Neck     V-Neck
3   Round      Round
4   Sweaters   Striped
5   Sweaters   Striped
```

I tried

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% 
  filter(category=="Shirts") %>% 
  mutate(category=subcategory)
```

and the result is close to what I am looking for, but it does not contain the rows 4 and 5.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: `indx <- category == "Shirts" ; df$category[indx] <- df$subcategory[indx]`. But this won't work if `category` is a factor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for a "dplyr" only answer (your question isn't tagged as such) but this is very straightforward with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[category == "Shirts", category := subcategory][]
#    ID category subcategory
# 1:  1        V           V
# 2:  2        V           V
# 3:  3    Round       Round
# 4:  4 Sweaters     Striped
# 5:  5 Sweaters     Striped
```

I suppose with "dplyr", you could try `ifelse` (and possibly `replace`):

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.character)  ## Convert factors to characters
df %>%
  mutate(category = ifelse(category == "Shirts", 
                           subcategory, category))
```

Comment: If you are going to use `dplyr` I recommend using `dplyr::if_else()`. "It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster." [See here.](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
df$category <- ifelse(df$category=="Shirts",
                      as.character(df$subcategory),
                      as.character(df$category)) 
df
#   ID category subcategory
# 1  1        V           V
# 2  2        V           V
# 3  3    Round       Round
# 4  4 Sweaters     Striped
# 5  5 Sweaters     Striped
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably a long way round (and nowhere near as elegant as Amanda Mahto's solution) but you can convert your category and subcategory columns to characters, do your indexing and updating, then convert them back to a factor.

```
df$category <- as.character(df$category); df$subcategory <- as.character(df$subcategory)
indx <- category == "Shirts" ; df$category[indx] <- df$subcategory[indx]
df$category <- as.factor(df$category); df$subcategory <- as.factor(df$subcategory)
```