# R: Replace values between two numbers with the number

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is the dataframe

```
sampledf = data.frame(timeinterval = c(1:120), hour = c(rep(NA, times = 85), 1, rep(NA, times = 5), 1, rep(NA, times = 4),1, rep(NA, times = 4), 1, rep(NA, times = 18)))
```

I want to replace the NAs in column hour such that values between 86th row and 92 (inclusive) and then between 97 and 102 (inclusive) should all be 1.

Here is what I've tried so far:
1. Getting the list of rownames with value 1 in hour column
2. Looping through (**This is what is not working!**)

```
ones = which(sampledf$hour == 1)
n = (length(ones)+1)/2
chunk <- function(ones,n) split(ones, cut(seq_along(ones), n, labels = FALSE))
y = chunk(ones,n)

for (i in y) {
  sampledf$Hour[c(y$i[1]:y$i[2])] == 1
}
```

Help me out, I'm new to R.

In python we have ffill method for this, what an equivalent here?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You can solve this pretty easily, e.g. with `dplyr` and `filter()`. There are numerous answered SO questions like [Change the value of a column, based on another column (for certain rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812609/change-the-value-of-a-column-based-on-another-column-for-certain-rows).

Answer (score 0):

```
sampledf$hour[between(sampledf$timeinterval,86,92) | between(sampledf$timeinterval,97,102)]<-1
```

Basically you subset sampledf's hour column by those cases where timeinterval is `between` 86-92 or (`|`) 92-102, and assign 1 to all those cases.

Comment: Thanks! same here: can we make the rownames dynamic? I don't want to make use of 86:92 and 97:102 since in the next refresh the values might change.

Comment: This is not dependent on row numbers, just the values you put in. You can replace the numbers with variables,functions or whatever

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign 1 to all timeintervals in the given ranges:

```
sampledf$hour[sampledf$timeinterval %in% c(86:92,97:102)] <- 1
```

If you want to assign 1 to cases based on the rownumbers of your data:

```
sampledf$hour[c(86:92,97:102)] <- 1
```

If you want to add a cumulated sum to your values as in your comment, you can just use the `cumsum()` function and do:

```
sampledf$hour[which(sampledf$hour == 1)] <- cumsum(sampledf$hour[which(sampledf$hour == 1)])
```

Comment: Thanks! can we make the rownames dynamic? I don't want to make use of 86:92 and 97:102 since in the next refresh the values might change.

Comment: Then you just have to use the first part of my example. This will ensure that you're always assigning 1 to values in the timeinterval column that falls between these ranges. It's already dynamic. Or do you want to make the assignment dependent on another value?

Comment: can we extract rownames of all 1s in a dataframe column? and make use here?

Comment: ok, there it is: `ones = which(sampledf$hour == 1)` it would give me all row names with 1s. can we now loop through and take i and i+1 to replace the values?

Comment: Fortunately, in R you don't need loops very often compared to Python. They're also not recommended due to a few issues also related to speed. Instead, R is concerned with vectorization, which means that you can manipulate all values at the same time. So, you can just do `sampledf$hour[which(sampledf$hour == 1)] <- cumsum(sampledf$hour[which(sampledf$hour == 1)])`

Comment: the above one keeps first occurrence of 1 as 1 but changes the second 1 to 2, third 1 to 3 and so on.

Comment: Isn't this what you wanted? To assign i+1 to each row in the index? Can you tell me what you want? Did you want to replace all NA's with 1?

Comment: Naah! What i wanted is to replace all NAs between two 1s with 1. I.e. my first 1 is in 86th row and then 92nd ... Those 86 to 92 should be 1. Plus those 1 will be in a group of 2. I.e. 86 & o2 and then 97:102