# Is there a dplyr function for changing part of variable based on extra column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Trying to change column c to take into account changes happening in column d.

'Ids' have 'outcome' of "0" or "1", and some have outcomes of 'both' depending on the week so in current_df this is labelled "2".

I want to change these to '0' and '1' based on info in 'week_of_change' column.

```
# current_df
id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
week=c(5,6,7,11,12,13,19,20,21,5,8,10)
outcome=c(0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
week_of_change=c(NA,NA,NA,13,13,13,20,20,20,NA,NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(id,week,outcome,week_of_change)

# new_df
new_outcome=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1)
new_df<-data.frame(id,week,new_outcome,week_of_change)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the value of a column, based on another column (for certain rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812609/change-the-value-of-a-column-based-on-another-column-for-certain-rows)

Comment: You could likely do this with a combination of `mutate` (`dplyr`) and `ifelse` (`base`), the stricter `if_else` (`dplyr`), or the slightly harder to learn but makes very readable code `case_when` (also `dplyr`).  Don't really understand your logic though, could you explain your reasonsing?

Comment: @BenG if I'm running a mixed linear effects model and exploring changes in additional variables and want to control for this factor across time, I need to know when the change happened. Technically 'outcome' here is an additional 'independent variable' that changes over time, that I'd like to add to my model, hope that answers the logic question.

Comment: @BenG I'm unsure if this would work for 6,000 ids?

Comment: It's unclear how you're trying to approach this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# new_df
new_df<-df %>%
  mutate(outcome2 = if_else(week>= week_of_change,
                            1,0)) %>%
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(outcome == 2, 
                           outcome2, outcome)) %>%
  select(-outcome2)
```